# JAX Pivot Table

Tags: pivot, jax

Does anyone know if there is a generic way to compute with JAX the grad of a function that applies a dataframe pivot table as part of its calculation?

Is there a generic way to compute pivot tables that can be compiled efficiently by JAX?

Thank you

Comment: I just realized that there is a numpy pivot_table, i will try that

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in pivot-table-like operation in JAX, but you can define one yourself. But as for this part of the question:

> Is there a generic way to compute pivot tables that can be compiled efficiently by JAX?

The answer is resoundingly No, because pivot tables by nature produce output arrays of dynamic shape (the shape depends on the contents of the input), and JAX cannot currently compile code which produces dynamically shaped arrays (See [JAX Sharp Bits: Dynamic Shapes](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/Common_Gotchas_in_JAX.html#dynamic-shapes)).

That said, here's one way you might implement a non-JIT-compatible pivot table in JAX.

First, the baseline in pandas:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3])
y = np.array([4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4])
z = np.arange(9.0)

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y, 'z': z})

print(df.pivot_table('z', 'x', 'y', aggfunc='sum'))
```

```
y     4    5
x           
1   2.0  1.0
2   4.0  8.0
3  14.0  7.0
```

And here's how you might do roughly the same in JAX:

```py
import jax.numpy as jnp

def pivot_table_sum(x, y, z):
  x, y, z = map(jnp.asarray, (x, y, z))
  row, i = jnp.unique(x, return_inverse=True)
  col, j = jnp.unique(y, return_inverse=True)
  data = jnp.zeros((len(row), len(col)), z.dtype).at[i, j].add(z)
  return row, col, data

print(pivot_table_sum(x, y, z))
```

```
(Array([1, 2, 3], dtype=int32),
 Array([4, 5], dtype=int32),
 Array([[ 2.,  1.],
        [ 4.,  8.],
        [14.,  7.]], dtype=float32))
```

But you'll notice that if you attempt to JIT-compile this, you'll get an error for the reason mentioned above:

```py
import jax
jax.jit(pivot_table_sum)(x, y, z)
```

```
ConcretizationTypeError: Abstract tracer value encountered where concrete value is expected: traced array with shape int32[9].
The error arose for the first argument of jnp.unique(). To make jnp.unique() compatible with JIT and other transforms, you can specify a concrete value for the size argument, which will determine the output size.
```

If you want the pivot table function to be compatible with JIT, you need to statically specify the expected output size. Here's a version of the function that allows that:

```py
from functools import partial

@partial(jax.jit, static_argnames=['size_x', 'size_y'])
def pivot_table_sum(x, y, z, *, size_x=None, size_y=None):
  x, y, z = map(jnp.asarray, (x, y, z))
  row, i = jnp.unique(x, return_inverse=True, size=size_x, fill_value=0)
  col, j = jnp.unique(y, return_inverse=True, size=size_y, fill_value=0)
  data = jnp.zeros((len(row), len(col)), z.dtype).at[i, j].add(z, mode='drop')
  return row, col, data

pivot_table_sum(x, y, z, size_x=3, size_y=2)
```

```
(Array([1, 2, 3], dtype=int32),
 Array([4, 5], dtype=int32),
 Array([[ 2.,  1.],
        [ 4.,  8.],
        [14.,  7.]], dtype=float32))
```

It's written so that if you over-estimate the size of the output, the results will be padded with zeros:

```py
print(pivot_table_sum(x, y, z, size_x=5, size_y=5))
```

```
(Array([1, 2, 3, 0, 0], dtype=int32),
 Array([4, 5, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int32),
 Array([[ 2.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 4.,  8.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [14.,  7.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]], dtype=float32))
```

And if you under-estimate the size of the output, out-of-range values are truncated:

```py
print(pivot_table_sum(x, y, z, size_x=1, size_y=2))
```

```
(Array([1], dtype=int32),
 Array([4, 5], dtype=int32),
 Array([[2., 1.]], dtype=float32))
```

I think that's about as close to a JIT-compatible pivot table implementation that you could hope to find in JAX.